# SSIS: import multiple files to separate destination tables

Tags: ssis

I'm new to SSIS.  I'm running BIDS under SQL Server 2008 R2.  I have several text files that I need to import into separate SQL Server destination tables.  The tables already exist in the DB.  Each file will map to only 1 table.  (For example, file_A maps to table_A, and file_B maps to table_B.)  My general data flow is as follows:

Flat File Source
Data Conversion (to handle the issue of unicode vs non-unicode strings)
OLE DB Destination (to handle the issue of local server to remote server)

Do I need to create a separate data flow task for each of my text files?  If so, my package may be very large.

Comment: Yes, do create a separate data flow for each file. Otherwise, you're going to spend a lot of time waiting for validation to complete. Plus, things can get ... odd when you have many unrelated things in a dataflow. You might be interested in creating a package per source file. Without knowing your business requirements, it's hard to say if that's a good pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a single data flow task that has more than one "flow" in it.   Hard to describe with words, but you can put a source1 that flows to DataConversion1 that flows to Destination1 and then alongside it (no connections) Source2 flows to DataConversion2 flows to Destination2, and so on.

However, I do agree with @billinkc that using a separate dataflow for each is the better way to go.   It will make debugging easier, in addition to the other benefits he mentioned.